# how to print the remaining time to download a file when using wget2

Tags: linux, download, wget

I am using the wget2 (version `2.0.0`) on Ubuntu 20.04. Trying to download a file, I have used the following command:

```
wget2 -c --progress=bar 'https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-arm64.iso.zsync'
```

The output is:

```
jammy-desktop-arm64.  27% [=======>                         ]    1.48M   56.73KB/s
                          [Files: 0  Bytes: 0  [0 B/s] Redirects: 0  Todo: 1  Errors: 0 ]
```

By default `wget` displays the total **estimated remaining time** . But for `wget2` I can't find any option to print the remaining time (the progress bar is not sufficient for me).

Is there an option for `wget2` command to display the remaining time to download a file?

Answer (score 1):

`wget2` cannot display the remaining time when downloading a file (it is not listed in the documentation, I cannot find anything that mention about remaining time in the manual https://manpages.debian.org/testing/wget2/wget2.1.en.html). If you really need the remaining time, you should use `curl` with `-o` option instead.

Example of my `curl` command: 
`curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.3/python-3.10.3-amd64.exe -o "pythoninstaller.exe"`

When downloading:
[image: Download with curl]

Comment: "wget2 cannot display the remaining time ... " why? any reference for this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @OK-Validation when I read the documentation. I cannot find anything that mention remaining download time (I read it from here https://manpages.debian.org/testing/wget2/wget2.1.en.html).

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my question. But I think an explicit affirmation is needed